# Left navigation bar moves together with content in IE (have to scroll independently)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have page with left navigation bar that can be scrolled.
The content can be scrolled as well.
It works fine in chrome, however in IE11 navigation bar moves together with content, and content together with navbar.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
}

    .navigation {
        position: relative;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 280px;
            flex-basis: 280px;
        -ms-flex-negative: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
        background: red;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
                box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .content {
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        -ms-flex-negative: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
        flex-basis: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 50%; // This makes the "content" div shrink when being resized
    }
```

```html
<div class"wrapper"> 
<div class"navigation"> </div>
<div class"content"> </div>
</div>
```

this is how my css classes look like.  I've tried adding `-ms` style properties but it didn't help.

seems like `overflow-y: auto;` property in `.navigation` class is not working. I tried inspecting and setting `overflow-y:scroll` in IE and it appeared but did not work either. I also tried `-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar`

I know it's just me not knowing how to solve these problems, but it makes me hate IE so much I can't even describe.

I've been trying to achieve that navigation and content would scroll independently all day and I miserably fail to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test your code in IE and Chrome. Based on my testing result, I find that your code is giving similar output in Chrome and IE which is scroll bar not get added to Navigation bar and it move together with content.

Test result of your code as it is in Chrome browser.

[image]

You can try to make a test with code below may help you to solve the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.col-container {
  
 
 
}
.col1 {
  float:left;
  padding: 16px;
  width:250px;
 height:400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background:red;
  
}
.col2 {

 float:left;
  padding: 16px;
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background:yellow;
   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<h2>Sample page</h2>


<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col1">
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
   <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <p>Content Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.
To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.
Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.
Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device.
</p>
  </div>

  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, it works when I set height, but I need height navbar to be the same size as size of content, I tried setting it to 100%  and it's not working sadly :(

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Let me know, if you have any further questions. I will try to provide further suggestions.